# How to stop getting the same number using random

Tags: java

I made this for class to get 7 random cards. Now want to modify it to get 21 random cards that are not repeating. I am trying to build another program that is a card guessing game. I have modified it to give me 21 cards but I always get repeating cards. I was thinking maybe use a seed. But I dont know enough about them to use them effectively.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SuchaDeal
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Random generator = new Random();       
    int i = 1;   
    String cardSuit;
    int card;    // a card number from 0 to 51
    int cardNum;
    String cardRank = "";

    while (i <= 21)   // loop through 21 times
    {
      card = generator.nextInt(52);   // Returns 0 – 51 
      cardNum = card % 13;    // number between 0-12 for the rank    
      //classify card into suits here

      if ( card  <= 12) 
      {
        cardSuit = " Clubs ";  
      }
      else if ( card  >= 13 && card <= 25  )
      {
        cardSuit = " Diamonds "; 
      }
      else if ( card  >= 26 && card <= 38)
      {
        cardSuit = " Spades "; 
      }
      else
      {
        cardSuit = " Hearts ";
      }

      //name the ranks
      switch (cardNum)
      {
        case 0: cardRank = "Ace";    break;
        case 10: cardRank = "Jack";  break;
        case 11: cardRank = "Queen"; break;
        case 12: cardRank = "King";  break; 
        default: cardRank = "" + (cardNum + 1);
      }
      //print the results   
      System.out.println("Card " + i + " is a " + cardRank + (" of ") + cardSuit);

      i++; // increment the counter
    }
  }
}
```

I know it is not the most pretty code but this is one of the first programs that I am going to write in java.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here? `new Random.nextInt(int)` returns a randomized number based on the range you give it. You can call `.setSeed(long)` to ensure it WILL deliver the same number every time, but by default it's seed is randomized automatically.

Comment: the code works for me.  Make sure you have saved and re-compiled.  *but I always get repeating cards*  or do you mean you are sometimes getting a duplicate?

Comment: if they want a shuffled deck they would be better off generating every card into a collection and then just using `Collections.shuffle(List<>)` or alternatively if a selection of cards but not a full deck is desired, selecting random indexes to remove from the collection

Comment: Basically, as suggested by other: construct a deck of 52 cards, shuffle it, and take the first 20 from the shuffled deck.  Another suggest is: avoid using a number to represent suit + number of a card.  Properly have  a `Card` class, a enum for `Suit`.  It should make your life a lot easier when dealing with the deck and card construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comment, you should do a deck shuffling instead of generating individual cards by random.

Another suggestion I will give is to properly model a card and suit.

pseudo-code:

```
enum Suit {
    SPADE, HEART, DIAMOND, CLUB
}

class Card {
    private Suit suit;
    private int number;  // 1 = Ace... 13 = King
    Card(Suit suit, int number) {....}

    // Getters, toString(), equals(), hashCode()
    // no setters, as this is good candidate for immutable class
}
```

Main logic

```
List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
for (suit : Suit.values) {
    for (num = 1 to 13) {
        deck.add(new Card(suit, num));
    }
}
// now you have a deck of 52 cards

// shuffle the decek
Collections.shuffle(deck);

// take first 20 card from deck, by whatever way you like
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this approach, you should increment `i` only when the card you've made is unique, perhaps storing the created cards in some array, and then checking if the newly generated card is already present, discarding it and re-running the loop/calculation if it is present.

However, if you're going to build a full deck, this approach is pretty naive - because the likelihood of randomly producing a unique card gets lower and lower as the number of cards already produced gets higher and higher. (Once you have 51 cards, you'll likely have to run this loop upwards of 52 times before you randomly generate the only remaining card)

Instead, you could build out a deck of 52 cards programmatically, or as a hard-coded array, and then use a shuffling algorithm like Fisher-Yates:

```
 static void shuffleArray(int[] ar)
  {
    // If running on Java 6 or older, use `new Random()` on RHS here
    Random rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      // Simple swap
      int a = ar[index];
      ar[index] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = a;
    }
  }
```

Now, you have a 'full deck' that's been randomly shuffled. Then, take the first 21 cards using [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(cardArray, 0, 20);
```

Comment: "likely have to run this loop 52 times" the correct way to say this is "have to run this loop 52 times on average" with your statement 52 is the wrong number, it can be 1 or 36 or something else depending on what you mean by it. 200 is also a good number with it you have ~98% chance to generate the card I would say this means likely.

Comment: You'll likely have to do something x times is the same as saying that the average is at least x. 

I don't think unpacking baggage around probability is helpful or relevant for OP's question or apparent skill level.

Comment: @Bricky No, it absolutely is not, they mean different things and the numbers are different and when you know the average adding 'at least' to it also makes no sense. Your edit didn't make it less wrong. Don't know how relevant it is to OP so I'm not going to downvote it, not going to upvote an otherwise nice answer that states something plainly wrong either.